# Coincidences in $\{\sum_k\left\lfloor\frac{k}2\sqrt p\right\rfloor2^{-k}\}$ and $\sum_k(\lfloor\frac{k}2\sqrt p\rfloor\bmod2)2^{-k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory

Let us consider the following sums:

$$f(p) = \Big\{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \Big\lfloor{\frac{k}{2}\sqrt{p}\Big\rfloor}\cdot2^{-k}\Big\}$$
$$g(p) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \Big(\Big\lfloor{\frac{k}{2}\sqrt{p}\Big\rfloor \mod{2}}\Big)\cdot{2^{-k}}$$
Here, $\{\cdot\}$ represents the fractional part function, and $p$ is a positive integer, typically a prime.

I have empirically obtained interesting identities for a few values of $p$. They are exact up to 15 decimals, which is the maximum precision I can get on my machine without using exact arithmetic. Are these identities correct? Are there more to be found, maybe a generalization?

- If $p = 23$, then $f(p) = 9/31$ and $g(p) = 7/31$
- If $p = 41$, then $f(p) = 2/31$ and $g(p) = 10/31$
- If $p = 97$, then $f(p) = 3g(p)$
- If $p = 143$, then $f(p) = g(p) = 1$ (correct up to 15 decimals)

Typically, the binary digits of $g(p)$ are 50/50 zero's and one's. This not the case for $f(p)$. Again, this is based on empirical evidence only. I have found in the past numbers that agreed up to the first 10 million digits but were actually different, so please take this with a grain of salt.

**Update**

More details can be found in my new question, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3484835/the-proportion-of-binary-digits-of-sum-k-1-infty-big-lfloor-frack2-sq).

**Context**

Of course this is related to my study of normal numbers, but more specifically, with the following operator denoted as $*$, associated with a group on $[0, 1]$, and defined as follows: if $x, y \in [0,1]$ then $x * y$ is the number whose $k$-th binary digit is the sum of the $k$-th binary digits of $x$ and $y$, modulo $2$.

Comment: Perhaps I’m misunderstanding, but wolfram says that $f(23)\approx 2.832588...$ and the first 50 or so decimal digits make it look pretty irrational... it does not seem to resemble $9/31$.

Comment: Actually, it does kind of match if you replace $\sqrt{kp}$ with $k\sqrt{p}$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Even in that case, Wolfram does calculate that the sum’s digits stop repeating themselves after about 20-30 digits. However, it does seem pretty strange that it is so close to $9/31$...

Comment: @Franklin, thanks, I corrected my formula. Yet it would seem weird that the equality is exact.

Comment: Ah, it’s not actually exact - see my answer below. There’s just a *very very small error*, but there is an error nonetheless, and the quantities are actually unequal. (My answer only concerns your fourth conjecture, though I suspect something similar is happening for the first two conjectures. I’m not sure about the third one.)

Comment: It could be that the ratio $f(p)/g(p)$ is a simple rational number depending on $p$, even though both $f(p)$ and $g(p)$ should be irrational, even if very close to rational numbers.

Comment: That’s true, and that’s why I’m not sure about your third bullet point. I do know, however, that the fourth bullet point is incorrect, and I suspect the same is true for the first two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can at least disprove your last identity and explain why $f(143)$ gets so close to an integer. We’re looking at the sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\lfloor k\sqrt{143}/2\rfloor}{2^k}\approx 10.99999...$$
Notice that this sum is *almost* equal to
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\lfloor k\sqrt{144}/2\rfloor}{2^k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{6k}{2^k}=12$$
But when we change $144$ to $143$, we are basically lowering the value of the term $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ inside of the floor just a little bit, but since the floor rounds down, *each* floor expression in the sum is decreased by $1$, and the sum as a whole is decreased by approximately $1/2+1/4+...=1$. However, it’s also decreased a little bit more, because $\sqrt{143}$ is not quite $12$, but it’s so close that the floor expressions $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ actually agree for the first couple terms. That is,
$$\lfloor \sqrt{143}/2\rfloor = 6-1$$
$$\lfloor 2\cdot \sqrt{143}/2\rfloor=12-1$$
$$\lfloor 3\cdot \sqrt{143}/2\rfloor=18-1$$
$$...$$
$$\lfloor 47\cdot \sqrt{143}/2\rfloor=6\cdot 47-1$$
$$\lfloor 48\cdot \sqrt{143}/2\rfloor=6\cdot 48-2\color{red}{\ne 6\cdot 48-1}$$
So the reason your conjecture is so close (but actually incorrect) is that this pattern holds for a long time, but fails after $k=48$, at which point the terms are being divided by $2^{48}$ and are thus incredibly small.

Comment: I would indeed expect that 50% of the binary digits in $g(143)$ are equal to one, which is not compatible with $g(143) = 1$. As for the binary digit distribution for $f(143)$, I am not sure. It could be skewed for the first few thousand digits; for the first 2,180 binary digits we have 2120 one's and 54 zero's.